# Modify the <display-name> in web.xml at build time with Jenkins

Tags: java, git, maven, grails, jenkins

I need to deal with several war files deployed in several servers in several independent environments. We use Jenkins to build the wars, that are generated by Grails based on code downloaded from a git repo. The wars are deployed in tomcat. The tomcat management page shows a "Display name" for each war. I want to modify that display name at build time with some identifier of the build, so I can poll the Display Name from all tomcat servers and detect if there are any wars with versions out of sync.

I undertand that the "Display name" is set between `<display-name>` tags in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

So my question is: is there any Jenkins plugin to modify the `web.xml` `<display-name>` value after a war is generated? or any existing tool that I can use to just modify that particular value of a given war file? (so I can run it from Jenkins as a last build step, pasing it the `BUILD_ID`). Any other options are welcome of course.

Answer (score 1):

The display name is generated using information in `application.properties` and environment name. Basically it is generated like this: `"${app.name}-${env.name}-${app.version}"`. You can modify name and version before the compilation adding a build step in Jenkins.

E.g. we use a Gant script to add extra information pulled from Mercurial to build name and version of the app. This is our script:

```
// File: scripts/PrepareApplicationProperties.groovy
target(prepareApplicationProperties: "set application properties") {
    def buildNumber = metadata.'app.number' = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER') ?: "0"
    metadata.'app.mercurialRevision' = System.getenv('MERCURIAL_REVISION') ?: "0"
    def mercurialRevisionNumber = metadata.'app.mercurialRevisionNumber' = System.getenv('MERCURIAL_REVISION_NUMBER') ?: "0"
    metadata.'app.version' = metadata.'app.version' + ".$buildNumber.$mercurialRevisionNumber"
    metadata.persist()
}
setDefaultTarget(prepareApplicationProperties)
```

More generic solution is what Mr. Haki proposes:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/grails-goodness-one-war-to-rule-them_4229.html  because he manipulates `web.xml` directly.

```
// File: scripts/_Events.groovy
eventWebXmlStart = { webXmlFile ->
    ant.echo message: "Change display-name for web.xml"
    def tmpWebXmlFile = new File(projectWorkDir, webXmlFile)
    ant.replace(file: tmpWebXmlFile, token: "@grails.app.name.version@",
            value: "${grailsAppName}-${grailsAppVersion}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll try something like the `_Events.groovy` hook option, maybe adding Jenkins environment variables to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps from the article didn't worked realy well for me in 2.5.0. So i've found out that this _Events.groovy works well:

```
eventWebXmlStart = { webXmlFile ->
    ant.echo message: "Change display-name for web.xml"
    def tmpWebXmlFile = new File(projectWorkDir, webXmlFile)
    ant.replace(file: tmpWebXmlFile, token: "${grailsAppName}-${grailsEnv}-${grailsAppVersion}",
                value: "${grailsAppName}")
}
```

And the step with install templates is not necessary